# How can I constantly fade an HTML button in and out with CSS?

Tags: html, css, fade

I'm designing an HTML game and I would like to know how I can constantly fade in and out the "START" button in the game with CSS.

- If jQuery is needed, that's okay; however, whenever possible, please use pure HTML and CSS. Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Usando_animaciones_CSS

Comment: @Gabriel Thanks, I'll take a look! P.S. [Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_Animations) is the English version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.pulseButton {
  animation: pulse 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}`
```